# Contenteditable Div Ignores Parent Div Margin in IE(9)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, margin, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I am building a custom rich text editor. And in its current use, it inserts itself- a div- before a text area that is nested in a div.

This container div is supposed to start out with a top margin that lowers it down on the page, and then the text editor div then sits inline with that.

The problem I am having is, in IE 9, when the editor div gains focus it immediately shifts itself so that its margin-top is 0px. This therefore occurs on the page loading, but also if the user clicks anywhere in the content editable div.

The caret remains at the correct location, but the editor div plus its container have scrolled upward so the editor div has no margin.

This works correctly in IE 8 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I'm not sure, but have you tried it in quirks mode?  There has probably been a fix to make the code work more along standards that doesn't work with IE9.  You can either use the built in tools in IE9 to try to identify the problem, or change the DTD and see what happens.

[W3 DTD List](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)